# Como auto calcular el descuento habiendo completado dos inputs?

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel y estoy implementando JavaScript para mi formulario donde tengo el precio de venta, el porcentaje de descuento, y el monto de descuento. Yo lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al ingresar el precio de venta y el porcentaje de descuento, automáticamente me haga esta formula (precioVenta * porcentaje)/100 = descuento, y me autocomplete el input del monto de descuento con ese resultado. Hasta ahora hice esto pero nose que hago mal que no funciona:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
    <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control" id="saleP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
    <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control" id="discountP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
    <input type="number" name="discount" placeholder="discount"  class="form-control"  >
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function discount(){
   var x;
   (document.getElementById('saleP')
   .document.getElementById('discountP'))/100 = x
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis es incorrecta, la función `discount` debería ser algo como:

```javascript
function discount() {
  let price = + document.getElementById('saleP').value; // + convertirá el texto a número
  let discount = (+ document.getElementById('discountP').value) / 100;
  //asumo que pondrás al input con nombre "discount" el id que he puesto
  document.getElementById('discountInput').value = price * discount;
}
```

Comment: Si pero me dice typeError: discount is not a function. Sabes porque podría ser ese error?

Comment: Oops, sí, fallo mío! He corregido la respuesta. El motivo es el siguiente: no debes tener `id`que sean el nombre de una función https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/467870/javascript-funci%c3%b3n-restar-no-existe-como-funci%c3%b3n/467872#467872